# Return method without returning any value JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, return

I understand on how to control the return statement but what and how does the return method work without returning any data but using JavaScript. I research somethings and post a thread about others but in this thread other web sources explains the meaning behind it but it's mostly teaching you it in alternate programming languages.

Comment: It just terminates the function, while returning the value `undefined`

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: @Pointy Their is a feature built into JavaScript which allows you to use the return statement without returning any value

Comment: OK? so what is the question? A `return` without an expression means the function returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not return any value. It will return *undefined*